# Mysqldump getting error only when trying to output to file

Tags: database, cmd, backup, mysql

I am using CMD to do a mysqldump. When I run the following command it works fine:

```
mysqldump -hmyhost -uroot -pmypass mydb
```

The dump works just fine, however, when it is done, it seems that no `.sql` file is created for the mysql dump and it just outputs the db data to the screen.

So, I was trying to output the contents to a file using the following command:

```
mysqldump -hmyhost -uroot -pmypass mydb > C:/mypath/tofile/testdb_dump.sql
```

But get the following error:

`mysqldump: Error: 'Table ' information_schema.files' doesn't exist when trying to dump tablespaces`

I greatly appreciate any feedback as to how to resolve this error and backup the db to an `.sql` file.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `mysql -u root -pmypass --opt mydb  --no-tablespaces > C:\mypath\tofile\testdb_dump.sql`

Comment: Sorry. i wrote it wrong: `mysqldump -u root -pmypass --opt mydb > C:\mypath\tofile\testdb_dump.sql`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still getting the same error `information_secham.files` doesn't exist.

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: In this [link](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65266) it says `Verified as described: error happens when 5.1 or 5.5 mysqldump tries to backup from 4.1 server. Version 5.0 is not affected.

Workaround: remove this error message from final dump.`. Maybe it is the same problem.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. That's interesting, but correct! My client version is 5.1 and my server version is 4.1. How can I remove / ignore this error while still create a mysql dump?

Comment: Try adding `--no-tablespaces`.

Comment: Thank you, the dump seems to work, I just assumed it wasn't successful due to the error, but seems to be working just fine and --no-tablespaces just prevented the error output :)